# Abort trap 6 after attempting to generate rails scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Chapter 2 rails tutorial, I am trying to generate scaffold using:

```
$ rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
```

I am getting the following error:

```
[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Abort trap: 6
```

I have tried to find this specific error with the abort trap: 6 on stackOF but can't. I am getting the same issue when I try:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

and even when I try to run the rails server

```
$ rails s
```

I found some info in the Ruby bug reports @ https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8373
it says that I may have older versions of extension libraries for Ruby. How do I get rid of these or clean it up so that I don't keep getting this error?

bus.ruby gives one solution, but being VERY VERY new to this I don't understand it. The following solution is given:

**"[BUG] unknown type 0x22" is most probably T_DATA for ruby 1.8.
You have an extension library (or more) for older ruby.
Try otool -L for followings.**

```
1 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.2.1/enc/encdb.bundle
2 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.2.1/enc/trans/transdb.bundle
9 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.2.1/pathname.bundle
```

Thanks so much for any help with this.

Comment: I figured out how to solve this. I think my gemset was screwed up when I updated OSX. Simple fix w/ `$ gemset-all do gemset pristine`

Comment: That was it.  How it happened is beyond me.  My issue may be because I upgraded Homebrew.

Answer (score 3):

The above comment from `user3353784` is correct. I was running ruby 2.2.0 and rails 4.2. The simplified command for newer versions of `rvm` is:

```
rvm gemset pristine
```